# Can't place message in MSMQ on server in DMZ using HTTP

Tags: http, msmq

I can't place a message in a non-transactional MSMQ on a server in our DMZ using HTTP.  In the IIS logs I'm getting:  2013-05-15 20:29:54 W3SVC1 192.168.32.XXX POST /msmq/private$/newprivate - 80 - 170.115.XXX.XXX - 403 4 5

Based on the 403 I'm thinking that I don't have permission to the queue (or the MQISE.DLL)

I've added permissions to the following accounts: IWAM, IUSR, NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICE and I still can't access it.  It works if I add a message on the box.

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, it works if I execute code on the server directly.  It doesn't work from another machine.

Comment: It wasn't working because we were requiring SSL on the root directory.  Now we are getting a 200 however it still isn't going into the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sending from a transactional queue to a non-transactional queue? This will drop the message. Turn on negative source journalling for the message. Set the UseDeadLetterQueue of the message to true.